# Cumulocity cannot publish message if I Disconnect afterwards

Tags: c#, connection, mqtt, cumulocity

I am trying to write a service to forward data to cumulocity.

When a sensor reads data, it sends it to our server. 
Then the server forwards that data to my service. 
I parse it and use Smart REST templates to send it to cumulocity.

I looked at the guides and copied the code there for some test.
For example a device creation message looks like this.

```
public async Task ClientTest([FromBody] JObject sensorjson)
{
    var cDetails = new ConnectionDetailsBuilder()
       .WithClientId("clientId")
       .WithHost("mqtt.cumulocity.com")
       .WithCredentials("Credentials")
       .WithCleanSession(true)
       .(WithProtocol(TransportType.Tcp).Build();

    MqttClient client = new MqttClient(cDetails);

    await client.EstablishConnectionAsync();

    string topic = "s/us";
    string payload = $"100,TestDevice,Test";
    var message = new MqttMessageRequestBuilder()
        .WithTopicName(topic)
        .WithQoS(QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
        .WithMessageContent(payload)
        .Build();

    await client.PublishAsync(message);

    await client.Disconnect();
}
```

When the code is like this, no device is created in my cumulocity tenant.

When I comment out `await client.Disconnect();`, it creates the device.

What is the reason behind this?

In my real code, if I don't disconnect at some point memory usage cannot be maintained. If I disconnect my messages don't go to the broker.

What should I do?

Comment: It's normally bad design to stand up a MQTT client to just send one message at a time. The usual pattern is to start the client once and reuse it over and over for each sensor reading, only closing it when the app exits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and time. I am new to MQTT so I didn't know the right way to use MQTT client. Memory leak starts when I try await client.EstablishConnectionAsync();  with already connected client. I need unique MQTT Client for each device with their deviceId as the ClientId. I changed the design to create new client for new devices and keep them while the program runs. For existing devices it finds their client and uses it to publish their data. Is this also a bad design? How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are publishing messages at QOS1 (At Least Once). This requires a multi packet hand shake between the client and the broker.

The `await` should mean that the publish code waits for this to complete, but it looks like it isn't which means you are shutting the client down before it can complete the handshake for the QOS1

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I didn't have chance to look at it over the weekend. I tried all three QOS modes and none of them worked. When I try to run methods synchronously I get "RunSynchronously may not be called on a task that has already completed" exception.